# Restrict Oracle database schema to login using Toad/PLSQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, oracle-11g, oracle-sql-developer

I want to restrict my Oracle database schema for example john to login to database using tools like toad or PLSQL developer. this schema is used for application login using JDBC thin client. I cannot lock or change the password because some of our senior developer have access on this schema. I want to restrict these developer to not able to login database using toad or PLSQL
kindly guide if there is any way?

Comment: There is a way, based on the name of the executable, but it is easily circumvented by renaming the executable.

Comment: kindly you please guide me..

Comment: how can I restrict this schema?

Comment: Why do you need to limit access to it? Can't you have users who need access it login via proxy so you can control exactly who has access to it?